# localStorage Performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, local-storage

I am using a jQuery plugin called [jQuery Phoenix](https://github.com/kugaevsky/jquery-phoenix). It is a plugin that makes localStorage with forms very easy.

My question:

This script auto-saves every second. I have a form with around 275 fields and it saves all of the fields.

(I know saving that many fields that often is a bit overkill, but it's the default setting. I'm going to change it to save on an onblur event but it will still be saving 275 fields every time the person changes fields.)

If it is saving that often, will I run into any type of performance issues in browsers?

I do not know much about `localStorage` or how it affects performance, especially when saving this many fields of data that often.

Comment: You can likely find out by measuring it but a better question is, do you really need to be saving 275 fields per second.

Comment: So, does it cause any performance issues in your browser? What exactly "any" browser means? Does `w3m` or `lynx` "any"?

Comment: @pvg - Not really, that's just the default setting.

Comment: @zerkms - Edited question to say `browsers`. I'm referring to the popular browsers, in other words, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE and Edge.

Comment: Open the browser and check. And if you care about performance, consider replacing jQuery for [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: @GolezTrol - Can't get rid of jQuery as I'm using the Foundation Framework which requires jQuery. What's the best way to check performance in a browser?

Comment: @Lynda every action takes some time to complete. Try it on the targeted devices and say if it fits the desired performance metrics. There are no abstract/single "performance issues" defined in the industry, every case is unique.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, you can optimise your use of localStorage a fair bit from what is proposed, but that isn't the question.

LocalStorage is pretty fast, as confirmed in some tests written about here:

https://gomakethings.com/how-fast-is-vanilla-js-localstorage/

they were seeing speeds around 12ms to write an object of 10,000 values and read it back again.

I had a play and storing each item on its own, and it tended to be between 70-100ms, but when you're 'only' dealing with around 300 values it's less than 2ms, this was the same if the values were strings or integers.

Here's the code I used, which is largely based on the code in the linked article:

```
// Timestamp before the test
var start = performance.now();

// Set/get data to localStorage
var count = 10000;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    localStorage.setItem(`perfTest_${i}`, i);
    var result = localStorage.getItem(`perfTest_${i}`);
    if (parseInt(result) !== i) {
        console.error(`${result} !== ${i}`);
    }
}

// Timestamp after the test
var end = performance.now();

// Duration of the test
console.log('It took ' + (end - start) + 'ms.');
```

The easiest way to run these tests is just to paste them into your browser's console!

Comment: I just realised I answered a 6-year-old question! Oops, but it does come up in Google, so I guess that's not the worst thing to have done?!

Answer (score -3):

1. Performance is surely going to differ and it will be an issue since internal implementation of `localStorage` is  browser specific.
2. There is also a time difference between first read and subsequent read.
3. Beside local storage has a limited capacity(though it can be changed)
4. Also you wont want to stringify before saving. This will be inefficient.

**Note:** If all 275 fields are not changing changing simultaneously you can you only save the changed field

Comment: That's another set of questions, not an answer.

Comment: @pvg changed the question part as note.